# Cross-compiling - retrieve target CPU and version

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm cross-compiling for VxWorks using cmake. When I run cmake the first time I have to provide informations about compiler, target OS etc..

In the cross-compile dialogue there are three target system settings I set:

1. **Operating System**
2. **Version**
3. **Processor**

*(followed by compiler etc.)*

While I can retrieve the first one using `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, i can't get the version and the processor.
Both return an empty string.

Here's an example:

```
MESSAGE("CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:   ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}")
MESSAGE("CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:   ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}")
```

**Output:**

```
CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:   
CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION:
```

My Cmake Version is *2.8.10.2* and target OS is VxWorks (if this matters - compiler are WindRiver GNU).

How can I get the version and processor I've set in the beginning? Or is this impossible if I cross-compile to an OS that's unknown to cmake?

*(Btw. Compiling works fine)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is not possible so far. I'm getting empty strings all the time.

However, there's a working solution, and i guess it's the better way:

### Before:

I specified cross-compile settings (Compiler and target system, *see question*), then it runs over VxWorks specific parts in the CMake list (checked with `if( VxWorks )` to ensure it's not executed when other systems are used).

### Now *(Solution)*:

I wrote a ***toolchain file*** and ***platform files*** for VxWorks and required processors.

**Cons:**

- I have to write some extra files:

  - Toolchain file
  - Platform file for VxWorks
  - Further Platform files for each Processor (and processor type, *Gnu* and *Diab*)

**Pros:**

- CMake list is much cleaner now
- Separate Project and Target settings
- Separate System and processor settings - easy to add new Processors in a very clear way but keep System settings
- I write some settings in the toolchain file and CMake loads related system / processor settings
- *...*